# PCB heater circuit for small lithium ion battery

Tags: pcb, lithium-ion, heat

I'm looking to design a heating circuit for a single-cell lithium ion battery (800 mAh pouch cell) used in a unit kept outdoors in an environment that is regularly below -15 °C. This is well below the minimum operating temperature for the battery, so I want to make a heating circuit that uses the excess energy produced from solar (and excess stored in the battery) to keep the battery within the operating range. The circuit will be fabricated onto a PCB that physically contacts the battery.

For this circuit, I have two features that I want:

- Adjustable hysteresis for the temperature. For example, enable heater at 5 °C and turn off at 10 °C.
- Adjustable power output to heating element.

I would prefer to adjust the hysteresis and power digitally from the unit's microcontroller (could use a DAC or digital potentiometer). The hysteresis part seems pretty straight forward with a comparator and band-gap reference(s), but I am unsure what to use for the heating element with adjustable power.

I have seen people simply using resistors, but this seems hard to make adjustable. Is there a better solution using MOSFETs or BJTs?

Note, the microcontroller only wakes up periodically, so the adjustable aspect could only take place during the wake cycle. The heater would need to work without the microcontroller constantly on.

Comment: Do you need adjustable power? Design it for worst case temperature (duty cycle close to 100 %) and give it a little bit of mass and the duty cycle will be adjusted accordingly automatically by your hysteresis regulator. Comparator, NFET and high side resistor/heater. Should be good to go.

Comment: I would prefer adjustable, as it could allow me to vary the power based on time of day (amount of sunlight). I was under the impression that most heating circuits are similar to a home thermostat where the heating element is fully on until reaching the desired temperature. Is that not the case?

Also, I realized that I didn't note that I only want the microcontroller to control the adjustable part of the circuit, not control the actual heater. I edited the original question to reflect this.

Comment: Just lose the hysteresis.  Electric heating elements don't do "partially on" very well, because whatever drops the rest of the voltage will also become a heating element (more resistance does decrease heating power).  You're better off allowing duty cycle, and you have no need for PWM when the comparator will provide automatic cycling.  You can use a DAC for the reference voltage, in order to have a programmable target temperature.

Comment: All that said, your heating power requirements likely greatly exceed the available power.  And putting the micro to sleep while the heater is running is a joke.  The heater does not need to operate without the microcontroller on.

Comment: Why would I have the unit draw an extra 10 to 20 mA keeping the microcontroller on if I don't have to?

Comment: The whole point of the heating circuit is to waste electrical power, creating heat.  If "10 to 20mA" times battery voltage is too much heat, congratulations, you don't even need a specialized heating circuit, you just need to control how often the microcontroller sleeps.  And if it's not enough heat, you can just assume the microcontroller is always on when heating.

Comment: If we lived in a world where the unit is enclosed in a near-perfect insulator, then your condescending response might make some amount of sense. Unfortunately, as my question indicated, the outside environment does indeed cause the temperature inside the unit enclosure to drop. It is ridiculous to assert that it makes energy-efficiency sense running the microcontroller (which does not touch the battery) to generate heat as opposed to running a heating element that physically contacts the battery.

Comment: How big is your solar panel if 10-20 mA is an unacceptable amount of overhead?  How big is the enclosure you are heating?

Comment: The area of the solar panel is 60 mm by 110 mm. The enclosure is roughly the same area and 65 mm tall. It's not that 10-20 mA is an unacceptable overhead, it's that it doesn't make sense to burn that current through the microcontroller instead of a heater touching the battery.

Comment: What are the chances of precipitation covering the photovoltaic source? Do you need to take that into account, for longevity? (E.G., Oversize source, wiper or ultrasonic vibrator)